# How to extract skin from an image using HSV thresholding and contouring in OpenCv?

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012, hsv

This is my code. Skin Detector is a separate class that does the HSV thresholding. I've got it covered.

```
`


using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


// Function Headers
void Display(String s);
void detectAndDisplay(Mat frame);

void drawStuff();
void showInputWindow();
void showCannyWindow();
void showContourWindow();
void FindContour(Mat skinMat);


// Global variables

 cv::Rect roi_b;
 cv::Rect roi_c;
 int thresh = 2;
 Mat img_rgb,img_gray,img_bw,canny_output,drawing;


// Copy this file from opencv/data/haarscascades to target folder

string face_cascade_name = "c:/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";
CascadeClassifier face_cascade;
string window_name = "Capture - Face detection";
int filenumber; // Number of file to be saved
string filename;

// Function main

int main(void)
{


//  Display("3.jpg");


    // Load the cascade
    if (!face_cascade.load(face_cascade_name))
    {
        printf("--(!)Error loading\n");
        return (-1);
    };

    // Read the image file


    Mat frame = imread("c:/Emma.jpg");

 //   for (;;)
    {
        // Apply the classifier to the frame
        if (!frame.empty())
        {
            detectAndDisplay(frame);

            // detect skin
            SkinDetector mySkinDetector;
            Mat skinMat;
            skinMat= mySkinDetector.getSkin(frame);

            imshow("Skin Image",skinMat);

            // for contour detection

    img_rgb  = skinMat;
    blur( img_rgb, img_rgb, Size(3,3) );
    cvtColor(img_rgb,img_gray,CV_RGB2HSV);
  //  showInputWindow();

    drawStuff();
    cv::waitKey(0);


    }

        else
        {
            printf(" --(!) No captured frame -- Break!");
           // break;
        }

        int c = waitKey(10);

        if (27 == char(c))
        {
           // break;
        }





    /*for (int s=3 ; s>=0 ; s-- )
    {
        Display(+s+".jpg");
    }*/

    getchar();
    //waitKey(10);
    return 0;
}

}


// Function detectAndDisplay
void detectAndDisplay(Mat frame)

{
    std::vector<Rect> faces;
    Mat frame_gray;
    Mat crop;
    Mat res;
    Mat gray;
    string text;
    stringstream sstm;
    Mat Test1 = frame;

    cvtColor(frame, frame_gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    equalizeHist(frame_gray, frame_gray);

    // Detect faces
    face_cascade.detectMultiScale(frame_gray, faces, 1.1, 2, 0 | CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30));

    // Set Region of Interest
   /* cv::Rect roi_b;  we need them global
    cv::Rect roi_c;*/

    size_t ic = 0; // ic is index of current element
    int ac = 0; // ac is area of current element

    size_t ib = 0; // ib is index of biggest element
    int ab = 0; // ab is area of biggest element

    for (ic = 0; ic < faces.size(); ic++) // Iterate through all current elements (detected faces)

    {
        roi_c.x = faces[ic].x;
        cout<<roi_c.x<<"/n";;
        roi_c.y = faces[ic].y;
        cout<<roi_c.y<<"/n";
        roi_c.width = (faces[ic].width);
        roi_c.height = (faces[ic].height);

        ac = roi_c.width * roi_c.height; // Get the area of current element (detected face)

        roi_b.x = faces[ib].x;
        roi_b.y = faces[ib].y;
        roi_b.width = (faces[ib].width);
        roi_b.height = (faces[ib].height);

        ab = roi_b.width * roi_b.height; // Get the area of biggest element, at beginning it is same as "current" element

        //if (ac > ab)
        //{
        //    ib = ic;
        //    roi_b.x = faces[ib].x;
        //    roi_b.y = faces[ib].y;
        //    roi_b.width = (faces[ib].width);
        //    roi_b.height = (faces[ib].height);
        //}

        crop = frame(roi_b);
      //  resize(crop, res, Size(128, 128), 0, 0, INTER_LINEAR); // This will be needed later while saving images
      //  cvtColor(crop, gray, CV_BGR2HSV); // Convert cropped image to Grayscale

        // Form a filename
        filename = "";
        stringstream ssfn;
        ssfn << filenumber << ".jpg";
        filename = ssfn.str();
        filenumber++;

    //  Mat ArrayDetectedFaces [] 

        imwrite(filename, crop);

        Point pt1(faces[ic].x, faces[ic].y); // Display detected faces on main window - live stream from camera
        Point pt2((faces[ic].x + faces[ic].height), (faces[ic].y + faces[ic].width));
        rectangle(frame, pt1, pt2, Scalar(255, 0, 0), 2, 1, 0);

        FindContour(frame(roi_c));

    }

    // Show image
    sstm << "Crop area size: " << roi_b.width << "x" << roi_b.height << " Filename: " << filename;
    text = sstm.str();

    putText(frame, text, cvPoint(30, 30), FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 0.8, cvScalar(0, 0, 255), 1, CV_AA);
    imshow("original", frame);



    Mat ccc = frame (roi_c);
    Mat bbb = frame (roi_b);
    Mat Img = frame;
    Mat destinationROI = frame( roi_c );



Size size(roi_c.width , roi_c.height);//the dst image size,e.g.100x100

Mat dst = bbb;//dst image
Mat src = ccc;//src image

cout<< dst.cols<<"\n";
cout<< dst.rows<<"\n";

resize(src,dst,size);//resize image

cout<< dst.cols<<"\n";
cout<< dst.rows<<"\n";

cout<< src.cols<<"\n";
cout<< src.rows<<"\n";


cout<< roi_b.width<<"\n";
cout<< roi_b.height<<"\n";

cout<< roi_c.width<<"\n";
cout<< roi_c.height<<"\n";

dst.copyTo(Img( roi_c ));

Mat FML;

//compare(dst,  Img(roi_c), FML , CMP_EQ );
    //cout<<FML;




    if (!crop.empty())
    {
    //  imshow("c", Test1(roi_c));

    //    imshow("b", bbb);
    //  imshow("result", Img(roi_c));
    }
    else
        destroyWindow("detected");
}




void Display(String s)

{
    Mat I = imread(s);
if (I.empty())
{
    std::cout << "!!! Failed imread(): image not found" << std::endl;
    // don't let the execution continue, else imshow() will crash.
}

namedWindow( "Display window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );// Create a window for display.
imshow( "Display window", I ); 

}




void drawStuff(){
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

    Canny( img_gray, canny_output, thresh, thresh*2, 3 );
    cv::dilate(canny_output, canny_output, cv::Mat(), cv::Point(-1,-1));
  //  showCannyWindow();

    findContours( canny_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );
    drawing = Mat::zeros( canny_output.size(), CV_8UC3 );

    vector<Point> approxShape;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++){
        approxPolyDP(contours[i], approxShape, arcLength(Mat(contours[i]), true)*0.04, true);
        drawContours(drawing, contours, i, Scalar(255, 255, 255), CV_FILLED);   // fill BLUE
    }

    showContourWindow();
}

void showContourWindow()
{
    cv::namedWindow("Fill");
    cv::imshow("Fill",drawing);
}

void FindContour(Mat skinMat)

{
img_rgb  = skinMat;
    blur( img_rgb, img_rgb, Size(3,3) );
    cvtColor(img_rgb,img_gray,CV_RGB2HSV);
  //  showInputWindow();

    drawStuff();
    cv::waitKey(0);
}`
```

After thresholding and contouring, the output is soemthing like this.!

```
  http://postimg.org/image/5ri87c2r5/
```

My question is, How can use this image to extract out only the features of the face (skin, eyes, nose, lips) and place it on another image. Will it work? Is there any easier way to do it?

If there is an easier way, please explain.

Its very important so please help me.

Moreover when I use copyto function, It doesn't give me an error but it also doesn't show any change in the picture.

Please don't mind excessive variables and bad programming. Its a test version.

Answer (score 0):

As far as, i understand that you use cascade and contour to get face.

Then try these steps,

> 1. detect biggest contour, which represent as face and remove all other small contours.
> 2. overlap your binary face image with original image to get your real face and then use some other threshold like [Ostu Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu%27s_method).
> 3. For eyes detection: use circle detection method to get eye ball, which will represent your eyes.
> 4. For skin detection: Use only hue because color is represented by hue and refer [my paper](http://koreascience.or.kr/article/ArticleFullRecord.jsp?cn=MTMDCW_2014_v17n5_547) for detecting skin.
> 5. And for other face features such as nose, try other threshold methods.

Hope this helps.

Cheers :)